# Referencing JAR files in XAMARIN Android app gives .so related error

Tags: android, xamarin, jar

I am referencing a .JAR file in a XAMARIN Android app. I am getting an error when I try to access one of the properties included in the class of that JAR file.

`Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/IncentDemoApp.IncentDemoApp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/IncentDemoApp.IncentDemoApp-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libhdxutil.so"`

Does Anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: Have you bound the .jar file? [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar)

Comment: Yes, I did still no luck.